# present simple and adding s after the Sentence

Tags: grammar

why do i have to add s after the word **causes** in the follow Sentence i know that it is because causes is present simple but when i look at the grammar it say i/we/you/they take drive/work/do etc. he/she/it take drives/works/does etc
but the Sentence dose not start with any of them

> Bad driving cause(s) many accidents.

Answer (score 3):

*Driving* here is a *gerund*—an *-ing* form of a verb which acts as a noun.

You can tell it's acting as a noun because

- it is modified with an adjective, *bad*, rather than an adverb, *badly*
- it acts as the subject of the sentence

Since it is the subject, and singular, it takes the 3rd person singular form of the verb: *cause**s***. It's not just 3rd-person pronouns which take that form: any 3rd-person singular subject takes that form.

- John causes many accidents.
- My nephew causes many accidents.
- Carelessness causes many accidents.